Different Concepts of Strict Monotonicity of Preferences?
While studying microeconomics using many books at the same time (Mas-Colell, Kreps, Varian and Jehle) I have encountered a problem that I don't seem to understand.
Varian defines strong(or strict) monotonicity of a preference relation as:
$$If \ \  x\geq y \ and \ x\neq y, \ then \ x \succ y.$$
Meaning that if the bundle x has at least as much for every good than y but they are not equal (meaning that x has more than y for at least one good), then x is stricly preferred to y.
But then Jehle (Advanced Microeconomic Theory) says that strict monotonicity is:
$$If \  x\geq y, then \ x\gtrsim y, while \ if \ x\gg y, then \ x \succ y.  $$
Given that $x \gg y$ means that x contains stricly more than y for every good in the bundle.
That said, don't these definitions conflict? I know that conflicting definitions are not necessarily wrong, especially among different authors, but I am still confused wether I am just misinterpreting the definitions and they are the same or they are actually different.

Jehles' definition requires x to have more goods than y for every good so that you can say that x is preferred to y, while Varian's implies that x is preferred to y if it has more goods than y for at least one good, given that for all other goods x has at least as much as y.
So, to Varian, if x = (1,2) and y = (1,1) and $\succeq$ is stricly monotonic, you can already say that x is preferred to y, while in Jehles' definition you can't.
Am I right about the different definitions? Is this actually a thing? Varian's definition seems to make more sense to me.
Obs: I'am an undergrad in economics introducing myself to intermediate microeconomics, so please be kind lol. Thanks

They are, indeed, not equivalent. The utility function given by $u(x,y)=x$ represents preferences that are strictly monotone in the sense of Jehle and Reny but not strongly monotone in Varian's sense.

It's not necessarily a contradiction, but more like Varian's definition is more permissive, while Jehle's is stricter. (These 2 are indeed different definitions)
For Varian:
the preference relation ≻ is strictly monotonic for bundles  and , if  ≥  and and  ≠ , then  ≻ .
For Jehle:
if  ≥  then,  ≳  (weak preference). However, for strict preference  ≻ , Jehle requires  >> , which means that  has strictly more of every good than .
Random example:
If  = (2,1) and  = (1,1), Varian says  ≻  because  has more of the first group, even though its a tie for the second. However, Jehle wouldn't agree with  ≻  since  doesn't dominate  in the second good. I.e.  ≻  would only hold if  was (2,2) instead.
So yes your intuition is correct.
